# Tensorflow : Transformer Model Decoder Target Input

Tags: tensorflow, keras, nlp, transformer-model

I'm quite new to Tensorflow and machine learning. Sorry if I haven't asked the question accurately or not making sense somewhere. I have recently got to read about and try to understand the transformer model, after its reputation in NLP and thankfully TensorFlow website has in details code and explanation.

https://www.tensorflow.org/text/tutorials/transformer#training_and_checkpointing

I have no problem understanding the code: the attention layer, positional encoding, encoder, decoder, masking etc.
When training the model, the input is the `sentence to be translated` and the one `in the target language`. where the target language is shifted and masked.

My problem is when the trainned model is used for evaluation, the mission is to translate `an unseen sentence` to the target language, and so the `input for target` would be an empty token, how would this empty tensor react with the trained model within the attention layer. Its empty? and in the first place what would be the effect of neglecting it.

To be more precise, please look at the screenshot below:

`tar_inp` in inputted in transformer, and loss is computed between `prediction` and `tar_real` but when evaluating the model, what is the function of an empty `tar_inp` do in the layer. Thank you very much sorry if it's a dumb question and may you please provide some intuition for understanding.

[image]

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?