# How to handle target decoder inputs for self attention transformer model during predict()

Tags: tensorflow, keras, transformer-model, attention-model

My question is essentially a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68306221/tensorflow-transformer-model-decoder-target-input), where I'm confused as to what to pass into the decoder during the predict() (i.e., call()) phase. I've modified tutorials found [here](https://trungtran.io/2019/04/29/create-the-transformer-with-tensorflow-2-0/) and [here](https://deepnote.com/project/TensorFlow-Transformer-Model-cuvRiHurQVqznajODH76xw/%2Ftransformer-2.ipynb/#00017-2e12c62f-5a45-4ed8-8189-a2f4155d5971) in order to create this script. This is being used for the purposes of self-attention on a time series dataset for regression (not NLP).

There's too much boilerplate to provide the full model so I'll write in the pertinent script:

**Transformer.py**

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
# The following imports are my custom Layers/Functions
from Utilities.MachineLearning.Keras.Layers.Encoder import Encoder
from Utilities.MachineLearning.Keras.Layers.Decoder import Decoder
from Utilities.MachineLearning.Keras.Functions.etc import create_padding_mask, create_look_ahead_mask


def create_masks(input, target):
    # Encoder padding mask
    encoder_mask = create_padding_mask(input)

    # Used in the 2nd attention block in the decoder.
    # This padding mask is used to mask the encoder outputs.
    decoder_mask = create_padding_mask(input)

    # Used in the 1st attention block in the decoder.
    # It is used to pad and mask future tokens in the input received by
    # the decoder.
    look_ahead_mask = create_look_ahead_mask(tf.shape(target)[1])
    target_mask = create_padding_mask(target)
    encoder_decoder_mask = tf.maximum(target_mask, look_ahead_mask)

    return encoder_mask, encoder_decoder_mask, decoder_mask


class Transformer(Model):
    def __init__(
        self,
        num_inputs,
        num_outputs=1,
        num_heads=1,
        num_layers=1,
        num_embedding_inputs=None,
        num_ff_inputs=None,
        dropout=0,
    ):
        super().__init__()

        self.encoder = Encoder(
            num_inputs,
            num_heads,
            num_layers,
            num_embedding_inputs,
            num_ff_inputs,
            dropout,
        )

        self.decoder = Decoder(
            num_inputs,
            num_heads,
            num_layers,
            num_embedding_inputs,
            num_ff_inputs,
            dropout,
        )

        self.output_layer = Dense(num_outputs, name="Output")

    def call(
        self,
        inputs,
        targets,
        training=None,
    ):
        encoder_mask, encoder_decoder_mask, decoder_mask = create_masks(inputs, targets)

        encoder_output = self.encoder(inputs, encoder_mask, training)

        decoder_output, attention_weights = self.decoder(
            targets, encoder_output, encoder_decoder_mask, decoder_mask, training
        )

        output = self.output_layer(decoder_output)

        return output, attention_weights

    train_step_signature = [
        tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, None), dtype=tf.int64),
        tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, None), dtype=tf.int64),
    ]

    @tf.function(input_signature=train_step_signature)
    def train_step(self, data):
        x, y = data

        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            y_pred = self(x, y, training=True)
            loss = self.compiled_loss(y, y_pred, regularization_losses=self.losses)

        # Compute gradients
        trainable_vars = self.trainable_variables
        gradients = tape.gradient(loss, trainable_vars)
        # Update weights
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, trainable_vars))
        # Update metrics (includes the metric that tracks the loss)
        self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, y_pred)
        # Return a dict mapping metric names to current value
        return {m.name: m.result() for m in self.metrics}
```

**SelfAttention.py**

```
# Don't worry about what Custom is, it's basically a modified Keras Model
from Utilities.MachineLearning.Keras.Models.Custom import Custom
from Utilities.MachineLearning.Keras.Models.Transformer import Transformer


class SelfAttention(Custom):
    def initialize(self):
        self.transformer = Transformer(
            self.batch_input_shape[-1],
            num_heads=self.attention_units,
            dropout=self.attention_dropout,
            name="Transformer",

        )

    def call(self, inputs, training=False):
        # TODO: What about `targets`?
        return self.transformer(inputs, training=training)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was no point in using a decoder as all the relevant information for time series data is used by the encoder block.